# An error prevented the view from loading

Tags: sql-server

I had fully working Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and running with no errors.

Now the problem is, when I want to create a new or open an existing integration project in the Integration Service Project. I am getting the following error:

> An error prevented the view from loading.
>
> Additional information:
>
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8007007E) (System.Windows.Forms)

Comment: Have you installed some new version of Visual Studio lately? Copying the dll's mentioned could help: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1380655-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can trust me on this one coz I just solved mine just a while ago, but you must have a working copy or ask a colleague for the ff:

Replace all below DLL's with a working one, according to link provided below, dlls seem like they are broken/corrupted:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\**msddslm.dll**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\**msdds.dll**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\**msddsf.dll**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\**msddslmp.dll**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\**msddsp.dll**

After trying above suggestion, please give feedback. If it fails, let me know immediately, i'll be glad to help. Cheers! :)

Reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1380655-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a colleague that can help you with the .dll files but you do still have access to the sql 2008 install cd then you can retrieve the .dll files from `trin_aide.cab` which can be found here `x86\Setup` on the installation media.

Open the `.cab` file using an application like 7zip.

```
FL_msdds_dll_215_x86_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8 => msdds.dll
FL_msddsp_dll_56133_x86_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8
FL_msddsf_dll_214_x86_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8
FL_msddslm_dll_217_x86_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8
FL_msddslmp_dll_56134_x86_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8
```

Rename them to replace the files below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\msddslm.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\msdds.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\msddsf.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\msddslmp.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\msddsp.dll
```